# how confirm / check weather a tag exists or not in XML

Tags: php, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I'm trying to read the XML using `DOM` parser. My `XML` is dynamic so I cannot say always all values / tags will present in the `XML`. In this case i need to check the tag whether it is exists or not before reading it.

I tried like this as well

```
if($val->getElementsByTagName("cityName") != null) {

}

if(!empty($val->getElementsByTagName("cityName"))) {

}

getting error : Fatal error: Call to a member function getElementsByTagName() on a non-object in F:\xampp\htdocs\test\static-data.php on line 160
```

Any solution to find the tag existence. As like has Attribute as we check weather Attribute is there or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Xpath to fetch the nodes, you can avoid the validation.

Load some XML and create an DOMXpath instance for it.

```
$xml = <<<XML
<phoneNumbers>
  <phoneNumber type="home">212 555-1234</phoneNumber>
  <phoneNumber type="fax">646 555-4567</phoneNumber>
</phoneNumbers>
XML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
```

Get the "home" phone number:

```
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber[@type="home"])')
);
```

Output:

```
string(12) "212 555-1234"
```

No "mobile" number exists, so the result is an empty string

```
var_dump(
  $xpath->evaluate('string(/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber[@type="mobile"])')
);
```

Output:

```
string(0) ""
```

You can count the numbers:

```
var_dump(
  [
    'all' => $xpath->evaluate('count(/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber)'),
    'home' => $xpath->evaluate('count(/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber[@type="home"])'),
    'fax' => $xpath->evaluate('count(/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber[@type="fax"])'),
    'mobile' => $xpath->evaluate('count(/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber[@type="mobile"])')
  ]
);
```

Output:

```
array(4) {
  ["all"]=>
  float(2)
  ["home"]=>
  float(1)
  ["fax"]=>
  float(1)
  ["mobile"]=>
  float(0)
}
```

Or iterate the numbers

```
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/phoneNumbers/phoneNumber') as $phoneNumber) {
  var_dump(
    $phoneNumber->getAttribute('type'),
    $phoneNumber->nodeValue
  );
}
```

Output:

```
string(4) "home"
string(12) "212 555-1234"
string(3) "fax"
string(12) "646 555-4567"
```

Full example: https://eval.in/123212